# Running a tasker task via SSHDroid (or adb shell)

Tags: adb, tasker, ssh

I'm trying to run a tasker task manually from ADB Shell, via SSHDroid. I'm
running the following in putty (Windows SSH client):

**am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK -es task_name
Silent**

On which I get:

**Broadcasting: Intent { act=net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK
dat=Silent }
Broadcast completed: result=0**

However, despite the existence of task "Silent", nothing happens.
Could it be because SSHDroid doesn't have the
net.dinglisch.android.tasker.PERMISSION_RUN_TASKS permission? If so,
how can I fix that? If not, what else can be the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved thanks to Bossman's [awesome proxy APK](http://code.google.com/p/tasker-proxy/downloads/detail?name=pl.bossman.taskerproxy.apk&can=2&q=). Install it and then run via SSH:

`am broadcast -a pl.bossman.taskerproxy.ACTION_TASK --es task_name TASKER_TASK_NAME_GOES_HERE`

It works flawlessly :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because SHDroid does not have permission to execue Tasker actions.

You could contact the developer of SHDroid and ask him to add the permission to the application. I haven't found exact contact info for him, but I found [his blog](http://berserkerdevel.blogspot.com/).