# How to send a variable value to and receive it in a task?

Tags: tasker, command-line

I've a OnePlus One with rooted Cyanogen OS 12 and [Tasker v4.8](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html). I've a bash script in PC which when exiting requires a Tasker's task to be executed. I've seen the question [Running a tasker task via SSHDroid (or adb shell)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9864/96277) and although the accepted answer didn't work on my Android, the solution is very simple. To call a task, do:

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "TASK_NAME"
```

However, that's all I can successfully do. During exit, my script needs to pass the exit status to task so that I can continue my processing on device based on script's result.

The [official guide for invoking tasks](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/invoketasks.html) is meant for programmers, so that didn't help me. Per the thread [Launch Task via Intent](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/XzlTcXv6ENI) I attempted various ways to pass a variable's value, but to no avail.

When we invoke a task from an another task, we're given the flexibility to pass values using two variables. Those two variables can be received by the invoked task using the name `%par1` and `%par2`. In my demo task, all I'm doing is Alert → Flash → Text → `Show me: %arg1 %par1`.

```
# For demonstration only, I created a task named "lol"

adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" "par1" --es "varValues" "received"
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" "%par1" --es "varValues" "received"
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" "Par1" --es "varValues" "received"    # I also changed the variable name par1 to Par1 in task
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" "%Par1" --es "varValues" "received"
```

All those said commands execute with this output

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Even sending this broadcast works

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK -d "task:lol" --es "arg1" "received"  # I setup a profile to listen to this intent and receive extra from it in a task linked to profile
```

But calling the task directly and then sending the variable value doesn't do anything.

So, where is the fault in my approach and/or how do I send to and receive in a variable value in a task ***only using command-line***?

**Note** that I'm not looking for a workaround. I'm perfectly able to come up with many workarounds to receive exit status from my script on device, but using intent appears to be the most straightforward solution of them and I want to learn this technique too.

### Update

I raised my query at:

- official forums - Tasker : [Invoke a task from command-line and pass variable(s) and/or data to it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tasker/CShLpm9oo5U/ZfMt0T6qDQAJ)
- subreddit Tasker : [Can variables be passed when a task is called from a command-line?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/3zajma/request_can_variables_be_passed_when_a_task_is/?ref=share&ref_source=link)
- privately to Pent, the developer of Tasker, using email

I received this  reply from Pent, both through email and on forum

> You would have to be able to add a StringArrayList extra to the adb call with -e, don't know if adb can do that.
>
> If so, to see the format you can look TaskerIntent.java http://tasker.dinglisch.net/code/TaskerIntent.java, 
>   the function addLocalVariable, if you understand java.

And that is exactly what [I later surmised](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133121/sending-a-variable-value-to-a-taskers-task-using-command-line-and-a-method-to-r#comment166970_133121) after posting this question.

Per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053693/4720957), I believe a string array can be passed using adb. So I attempted some queries but again met a dead end.

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" '{"arg1"}' --es "varValues" '{"time"}'
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" '{"par1"}' --es "varValues" '{"time"}'
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "lol" --es "varNames" '{"par1"\,"arg1"}' --es "varValues" '{"received"\,"again"}'
```

I also converted the intent to URI using `am to-intent-uri` and  tried sending the intent URI directly, with no success again.

### New update

Based on the readings *viz.* [1](https://codereview.webrtc.org/1151363004/), [2](http://www.slideshare.net/yossigruner/android-adb-51289739) and [3](https://github.com/agoransson/mvd), I'm absolutely sure that a string array can be passed through `adb shell am` using `--esa` argument. Example:

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --esa "par" "lol, cat"    # value lol goes in par1 variable and value cat goes in par2 variable
```

That said, this query still fails:

```
adb shell su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es task_name "lol" --esa varNames "arg1, par1" --esa varValues "lol, cat"
```

### New update #2

You can use stock Android 6.0.1 as a testing ground.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I need to pass string arrays and I've no idea how to proceed with that.

Comment: Am not sure if reading this right, you have an adb script, when finished, has to pass off a variable to a task in tasker correct? But the task in tasker is not reciving this variable, and you want it to receive the variable. Am I on the correct track?

Comment: It is a bash script, but yeah, at the end I want to call a task using adb and send a variable to it.

Comment: Okay, will post any helpful info if I find any, and good luck

Comment: @pure.by: thank you for suggesting this alternative and yes, I can use it, and I did use an another alternative to solve the problem. I posted this question *for the sake of learning* the most shortest method to achieve the target.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @firelord's findings and `am`'s in-app document (output of `am`, no arg). This worked on my phone running 6.0.1:

```
$ su -c 'am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK --es task_name TASK_NAME --esal varNames %VAR_NAME1,%VAR_NAME2 --esal varValues VAR_VALUE1,VAR_VALUE2'
```