# Run a Tasker task via ADB

Tags: adb, tasker

I'm looking for a way to run a Tasker task named **test** via ADB command. I found this thread *[Running a tasker task via SSHDroid (or adb shell)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/running-a-tasker-task-via-sshdroid-or-adb-shell)* and tried but did not succeed. All I got was

```
adb shell am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK -es task_name test
Broadcasting: Intent { act=net.dinglisch.android.tasker.ACTION_TASK pkg=test (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

So how can I run a Tasker task via ADB command?

Comment: Follow my question to get the answer: [How to send a variable value to and receive it in a task?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133121)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your question. I successfully ran a Tasker task via ADB (just wish it wouldn't require root permission). Please post the command as an answer below so that other people will know how and I can mark it as best answer.

Comment: It would be fine by me and I would prefer if you self-answer your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use MQTT to handle firing tasks from the command line.
This doesn't require root, or to be connected by USB for ADB.

Place this batch file in your path:

```
cat post.cmd
@echo off
set _tail=%*
call set _tail=%%_tail:*%1 =%%
mosquitto_pub -h %ip% -p %port% -i "My_pc" -t '%1' -m '%_tail%'
echo Topic: %1
echo Msg: %_tail%
```

Then make a profile using the "Mqtt client" app, listening to S10/#
(my phone is an S10, set any topic name you'd prefer)

```
Profile: S10/# (431)
Cooldown: 1
Restore: no
Event: Message Arrived [ Configuration:Main - (Your mqtt broker IP here) : # : msg : topic : : ]
```

Have it target this task.
(I couldn't share mine without giving you my MQtt IP address)

https://taskernet.com/shares/?user=AS35m8mBhJAezDTr0Lio7dopdLiBaKgozAOxoCXM7Mh8sS5hSvSst1kEMf5%2FJeJveB%2BsvU8%3D&id=Task%3AMqtt+Listener

Now from the command line,

```
post s10 taskname1=:=par1 etc
topic : s10
msg: taskname1=:=par1 etc
```